# Выдача False при попытки использовать input / len

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

Я написал простенький код, который проверяет в пароле количество символов.
Все работает хорошо, однако при input мне сначала выводится False, который влияет на конечный результат.

```
def password_checker():
    if len(input(5 > 6)):
        print("Sorry you pass is too big")
    elif 5 == 5:
        print("okay, pass is done23")
    else:
        print("okay, pass is done")

password_checker()
```

Comment: Вы ведь понимаете, что в `5 == 5` вы проверяете, равно ли пять пяти?

Comment: а что вы ожидаете от выполнения `len(input(5 > 6))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def password_checker():
    pasw = input("Enter the password: ")
    if len(pasw) > 6:
        print("Sorry you pass is too big")
    elif len(pasw) == 5:
        print("okay, pass is done23")
    else:
        print("okay, pass is done")**текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом**
```

Попытаюсь объяснить ваши ошибки.
`len(input(5 > 6))` - давайте разберём эту строчку.
Почти всё в пайтоне считываются как функции и `len` и `input` тоже не исключение из
правил.
Вы буквально говорите функции `input` выведи мне `5 > 6`в консоль, а потом прочитай что напишет юзер. Но так как нужен аргумент типа `str` то выдает ошибку. Значит вывод, что вы должны объявить переменную
с `input` изначально, а потом уже сравнивать.

Дальше разберём строчку:
`elif 5 == 5:`
Вы тут говорите напрямую машине: Если цифра 5 равняется цифре 5 то вывести следущее если основное условие не сработало, сравнивайте уже готовую переменную с `input` но не забудьте всё обернуть в функцию `len`

А вообще рекомендую для начала изучить азы работы пайтон, а потом уже делать свои простые програми